# BlueStacks image output for apps

Tags: computer-vision, real-time, bluestacks

I'm working on my own project for computer vision where I can look at the images coming from a mobile game, and then autonomously play the game based upon what features I detect in the computer images. This will be my first computer vision project.

I plan on using BlueStacks to run the app, and then to output the images. Once I have the images, I need to do a real-time analysis, and then control the mouse actions based upon the results of the CV analysis.

My question is how can I access the images from the apps from BlueStacks? What is the best way to do this?